# SQL expression for combining dates such that year/month/date comes from 1st, hours/etc. from 2nd

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, calendar

I would like to update a column of type DATETIME such that it takes year, month, and date from a parameter `@date` (in a stored procedure for Microsoft SQL Server 2012) but retains hours, minutes, seconds, etc. from its present value.

Is there a concise SQL expression for combining dates in such a manner (similar to what `java.util.Calendar` would allow) or special syntax for `UPDATE` to achieve this effect?

**UPDATE** here is a concrete example: `UPDATE` of November 1, 2014 3:30 PM to `@date` November 3, 2014 12:40 PM results in November 3, 2014 3:30 PM (i.e. only month, day, date affected, hours/minutes/seconds, etc. stay the same).

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide examples of what you are trying to do?

Comment: SQL Server 2010 does not exist. Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: @SveinFidjestøl SQL Server 2012 (typo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the date part from the @date parameter and the time part from the existing value in the column.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mydatetimecolumn =
    CAST(CONVERT(date, @date) as datetime) + CONVERT(time, mydatetimecolumn)
WHERE <my_where_clause>
```

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest just adding complete days:

```
select dateadd(day,
               datediff(day, col, @date),
               col)
```

If you want this in an `update`:

```
update table t
     set col = dateadd(day, datediff(day, col, @date), col);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    declare @date varchar(50)
    declare @time varchar(50)
    declare @date_time varchar(50) 
    set @time= (select right(convert(varchar(50),@date),8)) 
    set @date=(select left(convert(varchar(50),getdate()),12))

    set @date_time=(select concat(@date,@time))
    UPDATE tbl
    set col1=@date_time

     where...
```

Comment: not all all!!-it will give you only hours/minutes/seconds

Comment: it will display hours/minutes/seconds and eliminate the rest.

Comment: I can see why this should also work, but it seems a bit error-prone compared to the other answers.